# How to create a serving_input_fn in Tensorflow 2.0 for image preprocessing?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I am using Tensorflow 2.0 and am able to train a CNN for image classification of 3-channel images. I perform image preprocessing within the data input pipeline (shown below) and would like to include the preprocessing functionality in the served model itself. My model is served with a TF Serving Docker container and the Predict API.

The data input pipeline for training is based on the documentation at https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/load_data/images.

My pipeline image preprocessing function is *load_and_preprocess_from_path_label*:

```
def load_and_preprocess_path(image_path):

    # Load image
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(image)

    # Normalize to [0,1] range
    image /= 255

    # Convert to HSV and Resize
    image = tf.image.rgb_to_hsv(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [HEIGHT, WIDTH])

    return image

def load_and_preprocess_from_path_label(image_path, label):

    return load_and_preprocess_path(image_path), label
```

With lists of image paths, the pipeline prefetches and performs image preprocessing using tf functions within *load_and_preprocess_from_path_label*:

```
all_image_paths, all_image_labels = parse_labeled_image_paths()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(all_image_paths, all_image_labels, test_size=0.2)

# Create a TensorFlow Dataset of training images and labels
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
image_label_ds = ds.map(load_and_preprocess_from_path_label)

BATCH_SIZE = 32
IMAGE_COUNT = len(all_image_paths)

ds = image_label_ds.apply(tf.data.experimental.shuffle_and_repeat(buffer_size=IMAGE_COUNT))
ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

# Create image pipeline for model
image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(ds))
feature_map_batch = model(image_batch)

# Train model
model.fit(ds, epochs=5)
```

Previous Tensorflow examples I've found use *serving_input_fn()*, and utilized *tf.placeholder* which seems to no longer exist in Tensorflow 2.0.

An example for *serving_input_fn* in Tensorflow 2.0 is shown on https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/saved_model. Since I am using the Predict API, it looks like I would need something similar to:

```
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(...)

# Save the model with the serving preprocessing function
model.export_saved_model(MODEL_PATH, serving_input_fn)
```

Ideally, the served model would accept a 4D Tensor of 3-channel image samples of any size and would perform the initial image preprocessing on them (decode image, normalize, convert to HSV, and resize) before classifying.

How can I create a serving_input_fn in Tensorflow 2.0 with a preprocessing function similar to my *load_and_preprocess_path* function?

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issue when upgrading. It appears that the way to achieve this in Tensorflow 2 is to provide a function which the saved model can use to make the predictions, something like:

```
def serve_load_and_preprocess_path(image_paths: tf.Tensor[tf.string]):
    # loaded images may need converting to the tensor shape needed for the model        
    loaded_images = tf.map_fn(load_and_preprocess_path, image_paths, dtype=tf.float32)
    predictions = model(loaded_images)
    return predictions


serve_load_and_preprocess_path = tf.function(serve_load_and_preprocess_path)
serve_load_and_preprocess_path = serve_load_and_preprocess_path.get_concrete_function(
    image_paths=tf.TensorSpec([None,], dtype=tf.string))

tf.saved_model.save(
    model,
    MODEL_PATH,
    signatures=serve_load_and_preprocess_path
)

# check the models give the same output
loaded = tf.saved_model.load(MODEL_PATH)
loaded_model_predictions = loaded.serve_load_and_preprocess_path(...)
np.testing.assert_allclose(trained_model_predictions, loaded_model_predictions, atol=1e-6)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am getting `ValueError: Trying to read from list with wrong element dtype. List has type float but expected type string for 'map/TensorArrayV2Stack/TensorListStack' (op: 'TensorListStack') with input shapes: [], [3].` Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Oh ok, you also need to specifically say `loaded_images = tf.map_fn(load_and_preprocess_path, image_paths, dtype=tf.float32)`. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31055

Comment: Thank you, I'll update my answer to include the dtype. Did this work for you in the end?

Comment: Yep, worked. I posted my answer below. It simplifies your solution a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding and simplifying @harry-salmon answer. For me the following worked:

```
def save_model_with_serving_signature(model, model_path):
    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, ], dtype=tf.string)])
    def serve_load_and_preprocess_path(image_paths):
        return model(tf.map_fn(load_and_preprocess_path, image_paths, dtype=tf.float32))

    tf.saved_model.save(
        model,
        model_path,
        signatures=serve_load_and_preprocess_path
    )
```

Note: `dtype=tf.float32` in `map` function was important and didn't work without it. I found solution [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31055). Also I simplified the concrete function work by simply adding a decorator (see [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/save) for details).